# Open file with path over 260 signs length in WIndows

Tags: gvim, path

Is there any way to open file with Gvim under Windows 10 from path over 260 signs length with out mapping the path to network drive?

Comment: Why do you think this doesn't work?

Comment: It does not work in my case, Gvim 8.2 + Windows 10, both vim and gvim shows me empty content for any file with path longer than 260 signs, also filename completion does not work when the path exceed this limit. Notepad++ has no problem with the same files.